# Unable to find 'full-path' to my 404.php file

Tags: htaccess

I'm trying to find the full path of my 404.php file. I thought it would be like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
```

The reason for this is because I am trying to redirect non-IP permitted people to 404.php page using the .htaccess rule (written below)

My WordPress is at the root level of the domain. 404.php doesn't load however...

Here is the .htaccess rule I have tried to get working:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /index.php?error=404 ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?error=404

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^IP Address One$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^IP Address Two$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^IP Address Three$ RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - 
[R=403,L] </IfModule>
```

Comment: Technically you can just send them to any link that doesn't exist and that will trigger the 404 page.

Comment: I assume the lack of line breaks in your code sample is just a typo in your question? Otherwise, this is wholly invalid. However, it looks like you are trying to serve a "not found" page for 401/403 status... unless you have additional (PHP) code that changes the status, then the client will still see a 403 status, not a 404. Why not just serve the 404 directly (ie. `[R=404]`) if that is the intention?

Answer (score 0):

I just made it a full URL Path so `https://example.com/404.php` and that works great....kinda obvious - and I wonder if that is 'not the WordPress way'

Comment: Presumably you are referring to using an absolute URL in the `ErrorDocument` directive? This is not ideal as it will result in a 302 redirect to the error document (as opposed to an internal subrequest). (However, is there really a `404.php` file in the document root? This looks like you are simply redirecting to a non-existent file, which will then trigger WordPress's 404 response to be served. Like what gdaniel mentioned in a comment.)